# Dataflow Pipeline Design to handle Multiple Pubsub Topics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a pipeline which reads from Pubsub topics(windowed by the minute) and writes the processed results to BigQuery. I would like to have the tables sharded by time as well as some key from the data itself. BigQueryIO does provide options to shard by the window timestamp but I dont think it provides any option to shard the tables by some key from the input collection itself. If I missed some alternative for this, please let me know.

To overcome this problem, (Option 1) I chose to shard the source Pubsub topic itself by the same key and so, setup the pipeline to read from multiple sources and process them along separate branches and writing each branch results to BigQuery partitioned by the window timestamp which seems to work. What I would like to know is since the intermediate processing step in Dataflow can be agnostic of the source or the sink in my case, (Option 2) would it make the pipeline more efficient (in terms of resources and time) if I continued using a single Pubsub topic and add an extra transform before the BigQuery write step to partition the collections and then write to BigQuery.

Option - 1
+ Incurs lesser load on Pubsub duringboth read/write since even the combined message might fit into a few hundred KBs
- Read Step & Intermediate processing is done in separate pipelines (which might not inefficient for Dataflow)

Option - 2
+ The pipeline is cleaner
- Additional step to partition which also reads the same collection as many times as the number of partitions we have - but the number of collection items and the partitions themselves are pretty small - so, this should not be a bigger problem

I guess Option 2 makes more sense while reading through [Pipeline Design Principles](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/design-principles?hl=en) but I still want to clarify what I am doing is right.

Comment: I also have a follow-up question. Assuming I have something like `PCollection<KV<String, Set<FrequentItem<String>>>> output` wherein the keys are unique, I would like to write each of the value into a different BQ Table named based on the key (each element in the set is a separate row). I can write a ParDo but then, I would need to configure my own BQWriter since the BQWrite.IO works only on a PCollection, right? So, how can I structure the pipeline in this case? If there is a way to iterate through a PCollection efficiently, then I can trigger off separate ParDos for each value.

Comment: Is there a fixed number of keys that you know up front that you will want to write to?

Comment: Also, is the purpose of the Set<FrequentItem<String>> to perform deduplication on the FrequentItem<String> values?

Comment: The number of keys is not fixed but it should be in the order of 10-15 max and never more than 50 in the foreseeable future. So, iterating it might not be a big problem if that is where you looking into. As for the Set<> part, one of the libraries I use returns a Set which I am just carrying over. If being just an iterable helps, it should not be a problem either/

Comment: There is a benefit of passing around KV<String, FrequentItem<String>> instead of the KV<String, Set<FrequentItem<String>>> since this gives Dataflow the opportunity to execute operations across each (String, FrequentItem<String>) in parallel to the others in the Set instead of just parallelizing at the Set granularity.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am also facing a similar issue. I need to partition the Pcollection based on date field. But i will not know the date. I have to Groupby date and then create tables based on the grouped keys and persist its value in respective table. I am not able to convert the Pcollection<KV<Keys, Iterable<TableRow>> to Pcollection<Tablerow>, I believe only then I could apply bigquery write transform on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 seems like the appropriate choice based upon the assumption that you have a fixed number of keys you want to output to.

[image: Dataflow]

Reading from PubSub, you would apply any transforms that you may require feeding them to a **Partition** PTransform which splits the PCollection into a fixed number of output PCollections. In the diagram above, I labelled these A, B, and C respectively.

Afterwards you could apply the **Values** PTransform to produce a PCollection<FrequentItem<String>> and then feed this into a **Remove Duplicates** PTransform. This would give you the Set semantics that I believe you are looking for since **Remove Duplicates** applies to each window individually.

Finally, you would apply any additional PTransforms to convert your PCollection<FrequentItem<String>> into a PCollection<TableRow> and connect this to a BigQuery sink.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In `PCollection<KV<String, Set<FrequentItem<String>>>> output`, if we know that the keys are going to be unique and of a very small size, is there anyway to sequentially split the PCollection instead of passing it to a ParDo? I guess it does not fit well into the Dataflow ecosystem but just wanted to check if its even feasible?

Like in the above example, if I run the transforms A, B and C, I am going to end up with only one Set<FrequentItem<String>> in each case. So, instead of a ParDo, can I do something else more sequential hopefully speeding up the pipeline?

Comment: Dataflow fuses all the steps it can run together and underneath the hood the partition will be fused together with the steps around it removing the need for trying to sequentially split the PCollection. Further details are available here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc?hl=en#Optimization

Comment: Partition returns a PcollectionList, in that case how to identify the respective table that each pcollection in the list belongs to??

Comment: The elements that you put into partition `i` will be available in PCollection `i` in the PCollectionList. See this example in the comment of [Partition.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Partition.java#L45) which has students in the percentile `[0, 10)` in PCollection `0`, students in the percentile `[10, 20)` in PCollection `1`, and so forth.